# How do I unfollow an issue on drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site

How can I unfollow (i.e. unsubscribe from email notifications) an issue on Drupal.org that I automatically followed when I commented on the issue?

Comment: It's broken, see [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/56306) on drupal.org. I suggest you *subscribe* to that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unsubscribe to the issues for a project, for example the "Drupal.org web masters" project, you need to:

- visit the issue page for the project (http://drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters)
- click on the "Subscribe" link

  [image: screenshot]
- In the next page, select "None," and click on "Subscribe."

  [image: screenshot]

[Unable to unsubscribe to drupal.org issues](http://drupal.org/node/56306) is an old issue that has been opened in 2006, and it has been marked as fixed. I can confirm that unsubscribing from an issue queue works, as I have done it many times in the last years.

Comment: This method unsubscribes from *all* issues for the given project, not just one issue.

Answer (score 0):

To unfollow an issue on drupal.org, find the "Following" link. (If you are using a mouse then hovering over the link will change it to say "Unfollow".) Click on that link to unfollow.

[image]

The link should now say "Follow".

[image]